# Fundamental group - constructing homotpies

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups

[image]

So in this proof, that the fundamental group $\pi _1 (X, x_0) $ is a group, it involves constructing a homotopy from $f*e$ to $f$ and $f*e$ to $e*f$ and they say to draw these diagrams to get an intuition of how to construct the homotopies. I just can’t figure out what’s going on the the diagrams and how I use them to describe the homotopy. Can anyone give me an idea of what’s going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is from an old Topology Explained note that has sadly disappeared from the internet,
so I repost it here, thx to Elliott Pearl who TeXed my original plain text answer on
"ask a topologist"".

### Intro

We have a space $X$ and point $p$ in it.
Consider the set $Y$ of closed paths beginning and starting at $p$:
these are all continuous maps $f\colon[0,1] \to X$ such that
$f(0)=f(1)=p$.
On this set we have the equivalence relation of being homotopic:
$f$ and $g$ in $Y$ are homotopic when there is a continuous map
$H\colon [0,1]\times [0,1] \to X$ such that

- $H(s,0) = f(s)$ for all $s$.
- $H(s,1) = g(s)$ for all $s$.
- $H(0,t) = H(1,t) = p$ for all $t$.

Such a map $H$ is called a *homotopy* between $f$ and $g$, and we
will write $f \simeq g$ when such an $H$ exists.
$H(s,t)$, as $t$ varies, is a deformation (a path) from $f(s)$ to $g(s)$,
and this for all $s$ simultaneously and continuously.
Condition (3) is to make sure that all intermediate maps $H(\cdot,t)$
are all closed paths from $p$ (these are also called *loops centered
at $p$*).
This is an equivalence relation on $Y\colon f \simeq f$ by the homotopy
$H(s,t) = f(s)$.
If $f \simeq g$ by $H$, then $g \simeq f$ by the homotopy $H'$ that sends
$(s,t)$ to $H(s,1-t)$.
We reverse time, in a way \dots
And to check transitivity, if $f \simeq g$ by $G$ and $g \simeq h$ by $H$
then we get $f \simeq h$ by the homotopy
$$
F(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
G(s,2t)&\text{if $0 \le t \le \frac12$, and}\\
H(s,2t-1)&\text{if $\frac12 \le t \le 1$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $F$ is well-defined because $F(s,\frac12) = G(s,1) = g(s)$ by the
upper definition while the other definition for $t=\frac12$ gives us
$H(s,0) = g(s)$ as well.
On $[0,1] \times [0,\frac12]$ the map $F$ is continuous (as $G$ is) and
on
$[0,1] \times [\frac12,1]$ the map $F$ is continuous as well (as $H$ is),
so standard facts about continuous maps defined on finitely many closed
sets gives us that $F$ is also continuous.
Moreover $F(s,0) = G(s,0) = f(s)$; $F(s,1) = H(s,1) = h(s)$;
$F(0,t)$ is either $G(0,2t)$ or $H(0,2t-1)$ which is always $p$.
So $F$ is indeed the required homotopy.
This shows that being homotopic is indeed an equivalence relation on $Y$,
the set of loops centered at $p$.
The class of $f$ will be denoted $[f]$, and the set of all equivalence
classes is denoted $\pi_1(X,p)$.
We will show next that this set can be made into a group,
and it is called the first homotopy group of $X$ at $p$.

What will the operation $\ast$ on $\pi_1(X,p)$ be?
It will be composition of paths: if $f$ is a loop around $p$, and $g$ is
another one then we can define a loop $f \ast g$ as follows: follow $f$
*at double the speed* (so for $t=0$ to $\frac12$) and then g at
double the speed, from $\frac12$ to $1$.
In a formula: $f \ast g\colon [0,1] \to X$, where
$$
(f \ast g)(t) =
\begin{cases}
f(2t)&\text{for $t$ in $[0,\frac12]$,}\\
g(2t-1)&\text{for $t$ in $[\frac12,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f \ast g$ is defined on two closed sets, and their definition
concides for the intersection $t=\frac12$: $f(2 \cdot \frac12) = f(1) = p$
while $g(2 \cdot \frac12 -1) = g(0) = p$ as well.
And $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so $t \mapsto f(2t)$ and
$t \mapsto g(2t-1)$ are as well (compositions of the maps $t \mapsto 2t$
and $f$, and $t \mapsto 2t-1$ and $g$ respectively).
Moreover, $(f \ast g)(0) = f(0) = p$ and also
$(f \ast g)(1) = g(2 \cdot 1 - 1) = g(1) = p$,
so that $f \ast g$ is indeed a loop.

But all this is true for loops.
We have to define all this on $\pi_1(X,p)$, which is a set of equivalence
classes, under homotopy.
There is only one way to go:
let $[f]$ and $[g]$ be in $\pi_1(X,p)$, the classes of $f$ and $g$
respectively.
Define $[f] \ast [g]$ to be $[f \ast g]$, the class of the composition
loop of $f$ and $g$.
This seems to depend on the representatives, so we have to show it is
well-defined:
if $f'$ is in $[f]$ and $g'$ is in $[g]$ then $f' \ast g'$ is in
$[f \ast g]$.
Or put slightly differently:
if $f \simeq f'$ (say by $H$) and $g \simeq g'$ (say, by $G$),
then we have to show that $f \ast g \simeq f' \ast g'$, by some (yet to
be constructed) homotopy $F$.
The idea is quite easy: $F$ has to follow $H$ for the first half of the
domain, and $G$ for the second, mimicking the definition of composition of
loops:
$$
F(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
H(2s,t)&\text{if $(s,t)$ is in $[0,\frac12] \times [0,1]$,}\\
G(2s-1,t)&\text{if $(s,t)$ is in $[\frac12,1] \times [0,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$
$F$ is continuous on both closed parts (quite obvious) and the overlap is
for $s=\frac12$, $t$ arbitary.
In that case $F(\frac12,t) = H(1,t)$ on the one hand, and
$F(\frac12,t) = G(0,t)$ on the other.
But both $H$ and $G$ are homotopies of loops, so they keep $p$ fixed at
all times, so both sides are always equal to $p$.
So $F$ is well-defined and continuous.
\begin{align*}
F(s,0)&
= H(2s,0)&&\text{(for $\textstyle s \le \frac12$)}\\
&
= f(2s,0)&&\text{(as $H$ is an homotopy between $f$ and $f'$)}\\
&
= (f \ast f')(s)&&\text{for such $s$.}
\end{align*}
For $s \le \frac12$ we also have
$F(s,1) = H(2s,1) = f'(2s) = (f' \ast g')(s)$.
For $\frac12 \le s \le 1$ we have
$F(s,0) = G(2s-1,0) = g(2s-1) = (f \ast g)(s)$ and
$F(s,1) = G(2s-1,1) = g'(2s-1) = (f' \ast g')(s)$ (for such $s$).
So for all $s$:
$F(s,0) = (f \ast g)(s)$ and $F(s,1) = (f' \ast g')(s)$.
Moreover $F(0,t) = H(0,t) = p$ for all $t$
and also $F(1,t) = G(1,t) = p$ for all $t$,
so $F$ keeps the endpoints at $p$ for all $t$, as required by part (3) of
the definition of homotopy of loops.
As you see, it's quite a bit of writing out if we want all the details...

### Group axioms

Having established that $\pi_1(X,p)$ has an operation $\ast$ on it,
we would like it to be a group.
The first thing to show is associativity, so for all $[f],[g],[h]$ in
$\pi_1(X,p)$ we want to have that
$[f] \ast ([g] \ast [h]) = ([f] \ast [g]) \ast [h]$.
Or, working on the representatives $f$,$g$ and $h$:
$f \ast (g \ast h) \simeq (f \ast g) \ast h$, for loops
$f,g,h \colon [0,1] \to X$ at $p$.
So what do these maps $f \ast (g \ast h)$ and $(f \ast g) \ast h$ look
like?
The first is the result of first composing $g$ and $h$
and then composing with $f$ in front of it.
So on $0 \le s \le \frac12$ this map is equal to $f(2s)$.
On $0 \le s \le \frac12$ it is equal to $(g \ast h)(2s-1)$, which has
to be split again: for $0 \le 2s-1 \le \frac12$, or
$\frac12 \le s \le \frac34$,
we have $(g \ast h)(2s-1) = g(2 \cdot (2s-1)) = g(4s-2)$, while
for $\frac34 \le s \le 1$ we have
$(g \ast h)(2s-1) = h(2 \cdot (2s-1) - 1)) = h(4s-3)$.
So in short,
$$
f \ast (g \ast h)(s) =
\begin{cases}
f(2s)&\text{for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$,}\\
g(4s-2)&\text{for $s$ in $[\frac12,\frac34]$,}\\
h(4s-3)& \text{for $s$ in $[\frac34,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$

What about $(f \ast g) \ast h$?
Here we first composed $f \ast g$ in the usual way, and then composed the
result with $h$.
This means that for $s \ge \frac12$ we have that this map equals
$h(2s-1)$.
In the case $s \le \frac12$ we have to split again: at first we see that
$(f \ast g) \ast h$ equals $(f \ast g)(2s)$ here, so when
$2s \le \frac12$ we have that this equals
$f(2 \cdot 2s) = f(4s)$,
while $\frac12 \le 2s \le 1$, or $\frac14 \le s \le \frac12$,
gives the result $g(2 \cdot 2s - 1) = g(4s-1)$.
In short again,
$$
(f \ast g) \ast h (s) =
\begin{cases}
f(4s)&\text{for $s$ in $[0,\frac14]$,}\\
g(4s-1)&\text{for $s$ in $[\frac14,\frac12]$,}\\
h(2s-1)&\text{for $s$ in $[\frac12,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$

So in fact both maps trace out $f$, then $g$, and finally $h$
but in different *speeds* during the interval $[0,1]$.
How to find a homotopy?
One way to look at it, is to take the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$
(coordinates $(s,t)$) with two line segments in it:
$l_1$ from $(\frac14,0)$ to $(\frac12,1)$,
$l_2$ from $(\frac12,0)$ to $(\frac34,1)$.
At the top of the square $l_1$ and $l_2$ divide up the domain
$[0,1] \times \{1\}$ like $f \ast (g \ast h)$ does
$(0\text{--}\frac12\text{--}\frac34\text{--}1)$, while at the bottom
they divide up the domain $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ as $(f \ast g) \ast h$
does.
Now we contract the square down to the bottom line $[0,1] \times \{0\}$
continuously, and in the mean time we make sure that on each intermediate
stage $[0,1] \times \{t\}$ we let the homotopy trace $f$ on the leftmost
part:
from the point $(0,t)$ to the intersection point of $l_1$ with
$[0,1] \times \{t\}$; it traces $g$ on the middle part (between $l_1$
and $l_2$), and $h$ on the rightmost part, up to $(1,t)$ .
The equation of $l_1$ is $t = 4 \cdot s - 1$, as can easily be checked.
The equation of $l_2$ is $t = 4 \cdot s - 2$.
So the leftmost part on level t is given by an interval that starts with
$s=0$ and goes on to $s = \frac{t+1}{4}$ (solve $s$ from the equation
for $l_1$).
So this means that for $s$ in $[0,4t+1]$ we have to define $H(s,t)$ to be
$f(\frac{4s}{t+1})$:
at $s=0$ we have $f(0)$, and it increases in $s$ up to
$f(\frac{4 \cdot \frac{t+1}{4}}{{t+1}}) = f(1)$.
The middle part is delimited by $s = \frac{t+1}{4}$ up
to $\frac{t+2}{4}$ (also solve $s$ from the equation for $l_2$).
So we have to find a linear (for ease) formula $\phi$ in $s$ and $t$
such that $\phi(\frac{t+1}{4}, t) = 0$ and $\phi(\frac{t+2}{4}, t) = 1$.
Trying out $\phi(s,t) = a s + b t + c$, for some $a$,$b$,$c$
and substituting, we find that $a=4$, $b=-1$ and $c=-1$ works.
So we define $H(s,t)$ for this combination of $s$ and $t$ to be
equal to $g(4s-t-1)$.
For fixed $t$, this increases nicely from $0$ to $1$ when $s$ goes from
$\frac{t+1}{4}$ to $\frac{t+2}{4}$, so that $g$ traces its normal
trajectory exactly in this interval.
Finally, on the rightmost part, so for fixed $t$, $s$ varying from
$s = \frac{t+2}{4}$ to $1$, we want another $\psi(s,t)$ such that
$\psi(\frac{t+2}{4}, t) = 0$ and $\psi(1,t) = 1$, as above.
A linear map in $s$ (fixed $t$) that sends $\frac{t+2}{4}$ to $0$ and $1$
to $1$ is $\frac{4}{2-t} \cdot s + \frac{-2-t}{2-t}$ (check this!).
So (simplifying this by putting $\frac{1}{2-t}$ outside brackets)
we get that for the relevant $s$ and $t$ we must put $H(s,t)$ as
$h(\frac{4s-t-2}{2-t})$.
So summarising:
$$
H(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
f(\frac{4s}{t+1})&
\text{for $s$ in $[0, \frac{t+1}{4}]$,}\\
g(4s -t -1)&
\text{for $s$ in $[\frac{t+1}{4}, \frac{t+2}{4}]$,}\\
h(\frac{4s-t-2}{2-t})&
\text{for $s$ in $[\frac{t+2}{4}, 1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$

We have thus defined $H$ for all of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.
As to the boundaries between the areas (delimited by the lines $l_1$ and
$l_2$) we see, e.g., that for $s = \frac{t+1}{4}$ the first part of
the definition gives $f(1)$, and the second $g(0)$ and both are equal to
$p$.
Similarly for the boundary $s = \frac{t+2}{4}$, where we get
$g(1) = h(0) = p$.
So $F$ is well-defined (no conflicts on boundaries) and continuous as
it is on each part.
For $t=0$ we get $f(\frac{4s}{1}) = f(4s)$ on $[0,\frac14]$,
$g(4s-2)$ on $[\frac14,\frac12]$ (again fill in $t=0$)
and $h(\frac{4s-2}{2-0}) = h(2s-1)$ for $s = [\frac12,1]$,
hence we get exactly $((f \ast g) \ast h)(s)$ as $H(s,0)$.
Taking $s=1$ we get $f(\frac{4s}{1+1}) = f(2s)$ on $[0,\frac12]$,
$g(4s - 1 - 1) = g(4s-2)$ for $s$ in $[\frac12,\frac34]$,
and $h(\frac{4s-3}{2-1}) = h(4s-3)$ for $s$ in $[\frac34,1]$.
So this gives exactly $(f \ast (g \ast h))(s)$.
Finally, for all $t$:
$H(0,t) = f(0) = p$ (via case 1) and
$H(1,t) = h(\frac{4-t-2}{2-t}) = h(\frac{2-t}{(2-t}) = h(1) = p$ (via case
3).
Conclusion: $H$ is indeed a homotopy between $(f \ast g) \ast h$ and
$f \ast (g \ast h)$, as required.
This gets rid of the trickiest part, the associativity.

There is another way to prove that functions are homotopic: via the
notion of reparametrisation.
If $f$ is a loop at $p$, then a reparametrisation of $f$ is a map $g$ of
the form $g = f \circ \phi$, where $\phi\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$
is a continuous map such that $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1) = 1$.
This is again a loop at $p$: continuity follows from that of $f$ and
$\phi$,
while $g(0) = f(\phi(0)) = f(0) = p$ and $g(1) = f(\phi(1)) = f(1)= p$ as
well.
Moreover $f$ and $g = f \circ \phi$ are homotopic:
define $H_{\phi}\colon [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ by
$H_{\phi}(s,t) = f((1-t) \cdot \phi(s) + t \cdot s)$.
This is well-defined, as $(1-t) \cdot \phi(s) + t \cdot s$ lies between
$\phi(s)$ and $s$ so that it is a point in $[0,1]$, and $f$ is defined on
it.
Also $H_{\phi}(s,0) = f(\phi(s)) = g(s)$, and
$H_{\phi}(s,1) = f(s)$.
Moreover:
$$H_{\phi}(0,t) = f((1-t) \cdot \phi(0) + t \cdot 0) = f(0) = p,$$ using
$\phi(0)=0$.
And $$H_{\phi}(1,t) = f((1-t) \cdot \phi(1) + t \cdot 1) = f(1) = p$$ using
$\phi(1) =1$.
So $H_{\phi}$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$.
Now, given $f$,$g$ and $h$ (all loops at $p$), we consider the map
$\phi \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ given by:
$$\phi(s) =
\begin{cases}
\frac12 \cdot s&\text{for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$,}\\
s - \frac14&\text{for $s$ in $[\frac12,\frac34]$,}\\
2 \cdot s - 1&\text{for $s$ in $[\frac34,1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$

The graph is a broken line from $(0,0)$ via $(\frac12,\frac14)$ and
$(\frac34,\frac12)$ to $(1,1)$.
(Draw this!)
Look at $((f \ast g) \ast h)(\phi(s))$:
for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$ this equals
$(f \ast g) \ast h (\frac12 \cdot s)
= f(4 \cdot \frac12 \cdot s) = f(2s)$
(as $\frac12 \cdot s$ in is $[0,\frac14]$, see the formula
for $(f \ast g) \ast h$ above).
For $s \in [\frac12,\frac34]$ we have that
$\phi(s) = s - \frac14$ in $[\frac14,\frac12]$,
so $((f \ast g) \ast h)(\phi(s)) = g(4(s - \frac14) - 1) = g(4s-2)$, and
for $s$ in $[\frac34,1]$ we see that $\phi(s) = 2s -1$ in $[\frac12,1]$,
so $((f \ast g) \ast h)(\phi(s)) = h(2(2s-1) - 1) = h(4s-3)$.
So $(f \ast g) \ast h \circ \phi = f \ast (g \ast h)$ (check the formula
for the latter function above!) so that $f \ast (g \ast h)$ is a
reparametrisation of $(f \ast g) \ast h$, and as such they
are homotopic, as we saw.

What about the identity?
Define $e_p$ to be the constant loop:
$e_p(s) = p$ for all $s$ in $[0,1]$.
We claim that $[e_p]$ is the identity element of $\pi_1(X,p)$.
Let's prove it is a left identity element, so that for all $f$:
$[e_p] \ast [f] = [f]$, or $e_p \ast f \simeq f$.
What is the left hand side exactly?
$e_p \ast f (s) = e_p(2s) = p$ for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$ and
$e_p \ast f (s) = f(2s-1)$ for $s$ in $[\frac12,1]$.

So if we define $\phi(s) = 0$ for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$ and
$\phi(s) = 2s-1$ for $s$ in $[\frac12,1]$,
we see that $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1)=1$ (and $\phi$ is well-defined and
continuous!) while also $f(\phi(s)) = f(0) = p$ for $s$ in $[0,\frac12]$
and $f(\phi(s)) = f(2s -1)$ for $s$ in $[\frac12,1]$.
So $e_p \ast f$ is a reparametrisation of f and hence these maps are
homotopic.
An explicit formula can also be given for this homotopy:
$$
\begin{cases}
H(s,t) = f((1-t) \cdot s) & s \in [0,\frac12]\\
H(s,t) = f(st-t+s) & s \in [\frac12,1]
\end{cases}
$$
(obtained from the general homotopy between a map and its
reparametrisation after substituting the concrete $\phi$).
One can easily check now that this works.
We'll leave the question of right identity for later (or the reader
can find an argument why $[e_p]$ must also be a right identity...)

We also need inverses, of course.
Again, we'll only prove left inverses.
For a loop $f\colon [0,1] \to X$, we define the reverse loop
$\tilde{f}:[0,1] \to X$ to be the map $\tilde{f}(s) = f(1-s)$, for all
$s$ in $[0,1]$.
This traverses the trajectory of $f$ in opposite direction, so
intuitively, $\tilde{f} \ast f$ should be homotopic to $e_p$.
How to see that?
At level $t$ (so fix $t$ for a while) the homotopy should be a
loop starting at $p$ (of course) and going to $f(t)$ backwards (so $f$ in
reverse direction) in the first half of the interval, while going to $p$
(following $f$ forwards again) in the second half of the interval.
If we look at the square $[0,1]^2$ (coordinates $(s,t)$) with the lines
$t = 1 - 2s$ and $t = 2s -1$, we see a V-shaped section.
In this section (at each level $[0,1] \times \{t\}$) we let the homotopy
stand still at $f(t)$, while to the left it follows $\tilde{f}$ and on the
right of it, $f$.
So
$$
H(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
f(1-2s) (=\tilde{f}(2s))&
\text{for $s$ in $[0,\frac{1-t}{2}]$,}\\
f(t)&
\text{for $s$ in $[\frac{1-t}{2}, \frac{1+t}{2}]$,}\\
f(2s-1)&
\text{for $s$ in $[\frac{1+t}{2}, 1]$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then for $s = \frac{1-t}{2}$ we get $f(t)$ in both cases and likewise for
$s = \frac{1+t}{2}$.
At the bottom, so for $t=0$, we see that the middle interval reduces
to $[\frac12,\frac12]$, so we can discard it, and we are left with
$H(s,0) = \tilde{f}(2s)$ (for $s \le \frac12$) and $f(2s-1)$ for larger
$s$,
which is just $\tilde{f} \ast f$.
For $t=1$ we get that the first and last interval shrivel down to
$[0,0]$ and $[1,1]$ respectively, so that for all $s$ we have
$H(s,1) = f(1) = p = e_p(s)$.
And for $s=0$ we always have $H(0,t) = f(1) = p$ and $H(1,t) = f(1) = p$
as well.
So $H$ is a valid (continuous of course) homotopy between
$\tilde{f} \ast f$ and $e_p$, so $[\tilde{f}] \ast [f] = [e_p]$,
showing that $[\tilde{f}]$ is a left inverse of $[f]$.

Now we are done by simple group theory: a set $G$ with associative
operation $\ast$ with left identity $e$ and left inverses $\tilde{g}$ for
each $g$, is a group:
First note that the law $g \ast g = g \Longrightarrow g = e$ holds :
multiply both sides of $g \ast g = g$ with $\tilde{g}$:
$\tilde{g} \ast (g \ast g)
= (\tilde{g} \ast g) \ast g
= e \ast g
= g$
on the one hand, while $\tilde{g} \ast g = e$, so $g=e$.
Then note that for each $h$:
$$\begin{align}
(h \ast \tilde{h}) \ast (h \ast \tilde{h})
&= h \ast (\tilde{h} \ast h) \ast \tilde{h}\quad\text{(associativity)}\\
&= h \ast e \ast \tilde{h}\\
&= h \ast \tilde{h},
\end{align}$$
so we apply the law, with $g = h \ast \tilde{h}$ to see that
$h \ast \tilde{h} = e$ for all $h$.
Moreover:
$$\begin{align}
h \ast e&
= h \ast (\tilde{h} \ast h)\\
&= (h \ast \tilde{h}) \ast h\\
&= e \ast h\quad\text{(by what we just proved)}\\
&= h
\end{align}$$
so $e$ is a right identity and $\tilde{h}$ is a right inverse as well.

This concludes the proof that $\pi_1(X,p)$ is a group, in all its gory
details.
The group theory bit is just an elegant way for me to avoid writing out
two more homotopies, of course...

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you understand what is going on in the diagrams in the picture I attached?

Comment: @Anon they are illustrations for some of the constructions I mentioned eg to show the constant loop is the identity.