# Give explicit homotopy between $\overline\sigma\sigma$ and the constant loop at $x_0$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\sigma : [0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a continuous path with $\sigma(0) = x_0$. Let $\overline\sigma(t) := \sigma(1 − t)$. Give an explicit homotopy between $\sigma·\overline\sigma$ and the constant loop at $x_0$.

With my definitions I came to these points:

- Loop at $x_0$: $\exists f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ with $f(0)=f(1)=x_0$
- $\overline\sigma (0)=\sigma (1)$ and $\overline\sigma (1)=\sigma (0)=x_0$

Now I want to find (?) a function $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ continuous with $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=\sigma (x)$ for every $x\in[0,1]$.

Consider (?) $H(0,0)=H(1,0)=x_0$, $H(x,1)=\sigma(x)$ and $H(0,1)=\sigma(0)=x_0$, $H(1,1)=\sigma (1))=\overline\sigma (0)$.

I'm not sure how do I have to proceed and what $\sigma·\overline\sigma$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explain the operation $\cdot$ (or $\ast$) for paths and loops in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3855420/4280).

$\sigma \cdot\bar{\sigma}$ is the loop defined by

$$p(t) = \begin{cases}
\sigma(2t) & t \in [0,\frac12]\\
\bar{\sigma}(2t-1) = \sigma(2-2t) & t \in [\frac12,1]\\
\end{cases}$$

In the linked post I give an explicit homotopy between the product of a loop and its inverse, with the constant loop; twowards the end of the group axioms part. This could serve you as an inspiration for your own homotopy perhaps.

Comment: I defined the homotopy $H(x,t):= \sigma \cdot \bar \sigma (x) (1-t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x) t$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1$. 

How can I prove that $H$ is continous? I've already shown that $\sigma \cdot \bar \sigma (x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @reij probably by the glueing lemma, as we do for $\sigma \cdot \bar{\sigma}$ as well.